# Nerd Fonts folder icon not showing up

Tags: neovim

I have installed Nerd Fonts and selected one of the nerd fonts for my terminal.

For some reason, the default folder icon set in Nvchad config in Nvim Tree just shows up as an Asian character.

I tried different terminals, Gnome terminal and Guake. I also tried to open the nvimtree.lua config file from Nvchad in both Nvim and Vim, and only the default folder icon is showing up this way.

I have updated my Nvchad and NerdFonts to the latest release. I also tried to download the lua config file directly from Github, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the newer version of your font as nerd-fonts have been updated recently. For example, you have to download the new version of 'MesloLGL Nerd Font' and install it in your fonts.

Also, you must make sure your code (nvimtree.lua) has [fragment of nvimtree.lua code] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmjPZ.png) the correct icons!

Answer (score 0):

You're experiencing issues with certain tools like Nvchad due to outdated versions of Nerd Fonts, I recommend obtaining your preferred font directly from the GitHub repository. Navigate to the "patched-fonts" folder within the repository at the following link:

[GitHub Repository - Nerd Fonts](https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/tree/master/patched-fonts)

Downloading the font directly from this source ensures you're using the latest patches and fixes, which should help alleviate any compatibility problems with tools like Nvchad.